# owl carousel how to use callback function values

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I want to use the value of event.item.count in owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', index)

On load, I want the carousel to scroll to the last item available, this is fine if you have a set number of items, but my items list (up coming events) is dynamic and always being added to. I see you can see the total items in the callback event fn  `owl.on('initialize.owl.carousel',function(){})` but how can i get that value out  to use in `owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', items)`

var owl = $('.owl-carousel')

```
// on initialise...
owl.on('initialize.owl.carousel', event => {
    //get this var out???? 
    var items = event.item.count

})

// attach the carousel and set the params
owl.owlCarousel({
    margin: 50,
    nav: false
})
//event handler
//HERE I WANT TO USE THE ITEMS VALUE
owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', items)
```

the err in the console
`Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined`

Comment: so simple.... 
```owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', -1)```  
 thanks @Alex-HM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counting all Elements and then getting the last index you could just use `-1` in the trigger event which automatically scrolls to the last element.

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();

$('#btn1').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', 0)
})
$('#btn2').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', -1)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn1">go to first</button>
<button id="btn2">go to last</button>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`items is not defined` because it's declared inside a function and you try to access it outside of that function.
You could move `owl.trigger` inside the callback so it has access to the `items` variable.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel')

// on initialise...
owl.on('initialize.owl.carousel', event => {
    //get this var out???? 
    var items = event.item.count
    //event handler
    owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', items)
})

// attach the carousel and set the params
owl.owlCarousel({
    margin: 50,
    nav: false
})
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that but i doesn' work... the owl cannot be inside another function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you got this error because you declare `items` in a function (`owl.on`) and try to access it from out of function.
Why you do not make a function which returns a count

```
function getCount(){
  return count;
}

owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', getCount());
```